# Unexpected NSLayoutConstraint behaviour in IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nslayoutconstraint

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I am getting this issue, only in iOS versions prior to 8

The selected view in the very first screen shot is a UIImageView. you can also see the constraints i have connected. I need to make the image view circular, so i am using layer.cornerRadius property. normally for circular UIImageView we use cornerRadius = height/2.0

but when i am setting this property in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method. some how its giving me a square imageview.

as you can see i have set aspect ratio of image 1:1
so it can be turned into circular UIImageView.

I know I must be missing out some facts about NSLayoutConstraints. please help me out

**My Code :-**

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
float height = profile_InfoSubView_ProfilePic.bounds.size.height;
float width = profile_InfoSubView_ProfilePic.bounds.size.width;
NSLog(@"(w,h)= %0.0f , %0.0f",width,height);
float cr = height/2.0;
profile_InfoSubView_ProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = cr;
profile_InfoSubView_ProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
profile_InfoSubView_ProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
profile_InfoSubView_ProfilePic.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

}
```

**Console Output**

```
2015-09-08 10:42:35.156 MyApp[821:60b] (w,h)= 240 , 128
```

as you can see even after setting image aspect ration to 1:1, its not square

**Output On Device (iPhone 4 - iOS 7.1 )**
[image]

Comment: MyApp[821:60b] (w,h)= 240 , 128 - It's not the same what you have there in the Storyboard.

Comment: @RohitKumar : I think the size is changing because of the constraints i have set for image view. but aspect ratio is also changing, which is really strange.

Comment: Use hard code value to test...ie: cornerRadius = 40;

Comment: with the hard coded one  . it will of course work correctly. i already tried that.

Comment: Then make the IBOutlet of the width/height constraint and then set your cornerRadius in viewDidLoad instead in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Since it's not returning the actual frame of your imageView.

Comment: Check priority of constrtaints for heigh = width for ImageView must be 1000, and contraints for  UILabel from right side check too.

Comment: @RohitKumar Thanks, it worked for me.